# How to accelerate the touchpad and the trackpoint on Thinkpad? set-prop commands stopped working!

Tags: touchpad

```
xinput set-prop 11 325 0.4
property '325' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format

xinput set-prop 14 325 0.8
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  21
```

I am on Ubuntu 20.10. Those commands used to work but from some reason they don't anymore. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Can I confirm your version? You’re using Ubuntu 20.10 and not 21.10? 

Comment: yes, according to `cat /etc/lsb-release`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the numbers changed so the acceleration is no longer 325 but 326. This command works: `xinput set-prop 11 326 0.4`